# Как использовать переменную типа Type для приведения типа?

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача стоит так: в зависимости от значения Enum'а в DC.DocType создавать различные формы WPF, а потом работать с ними единообразно. Формы не связаны интерфейсом, и я собираюсь использовать только базовые члены WPF форм, типа ShowDialog()

Пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде этого, но приведение к нужному типу потом не получается. Объясните, пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу?

```
        object dlg;
        Type tp;

        switch (DC.DocType)
        {
            case QuestionnairesDocTypes.FormV:
                dlg = new CreateFormV1View();
                tp = typeof(CreateFormV1View); break;
            case QuestionnairesDocTypes.FormL:
                dlg = new CreateFormL1View();
                tp = typeof(CreateFormV1View); break;
            // ...
        }

        if ((dlg as tp).ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            // ....
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте переменной `dlg` тип `Window`. Тогда не нужны будут никакие приведения типов:

```
Window dlg;

switch (DC.DocType)
{
    case QuestionnairesDocTypes.FormV:
        dlg = new CreateFormV1View();
        break;
    case QuestionnairesDocTypes.FormL:
        dlg = new CreateFormL1View();
        break;
    // ...
}

if (dlg.ShowDialog())
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Речь идет о формах WPF. Они не совместимы с типом System.Windows.Form. В вашем варианте требует указать спецификацию для Form, и все, что приходит в голову указать - это System.Windows. А тогда невозможна инициализация.

Comment: @АндрейКутасевич Что бы такой путаницы не было, стоит сразу называть все своим языком. В WPF нету "форм (Form)", есть "окна (Window)"...

Comment: Евгений, благодарю! Ваше уточнение ответа помогло решить задачу.